# Replace reapeted element in an array

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, rcpp

I have been trying to replace element occurring multiple times in an array with a particular formula. To be exact consider that in an array value x has occurred k times I need to replace all the occurrences of x with x+(k-1)/2. for example say 2 has occurred 2 times then replace all occurrence of 2 with 2.5.

My Idea of doing this is to maintain an array of same length as the input as a flag to check whether a particular element is checked.and this takes O(n^2) time. The code is as follows.

```
NumericVector replaceRepetedValues(NumericVector x){
   logicalVector flag(x.size());
   for(int i=0;i<x.size();i++){
     int count=0;
     std::vector<int> index;

     for(int j=i+1;j<x.size();j++){
      if(x[i]==x[j]){
       count++;
       index.push_back(j);           
      }
     }
     if(count>0){
       for(std::vector<int>::iterator it=index.begin();it!=it.end();it++){
         x[*it]=x[*it]+(count-1)/2;
       }
     } 
   }
}
```

Is there any efficient implementation for this problem?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Why not get a count of x first? Then restart and replace every x with the formula that's based on this count. That is not O(n^2), but linear.

Comment: If you are looking for reduction of memory usage consider an array of integers that record the number of occurrences of each element.

Comment: @RedAlert I think now the question is clear

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, The count is what took O(N^2) time to calculate. But Hash map seem to do the trick in O(N) time. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: @Michael Hash Map solved my problem of counting the number of occurrences in linear time. Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get your counts in O(N) time by using a hashmap (`std::unordered_map`). Something like:

```
std::vector<int> x = buildMyVector();
std::unordered_map<int, int> counts;
for(int val : x)
   counts[val]++;
```

Then a second O(N) operation could do the update:

```
for(int& val : x)
{
   int count = counts[val];
   if(count > 1) // could technically skip this since (1 - 1) / 2 is 0
      val += (count - 1) / 2;
}
```

However, since x is a `vector<int>`, integer division will always be used; i.e. you will not get 2.5 in your example, you'll just get two. If you want 2.5, you'll need to change `vector<int>` to `vector<double>` (or `float`). This could mess up your comparisons, though (should 2.0000000001 == 2.0?), so you'd need to rethink how you'd handle that. If the input is always `int` but the output can be `double`, maybe this:

```
std::vector<double> output;
output.reserve(x.size());

for(int val : x)
{
   double newVal = static_cast<double>(val);
   int count = counts[val];
   if(count > 1) // could technically skip this since (1 - 1) / 2 is 0
      newVal += (count - 1.0) / 2.0;
   output.push_back(newVal);
}
```

Comment: Thank You this is an elegant solution

Comment: Its not a problem I can just get the output in a float vector. so need for messy cross type comparison. I don't get it. There isn't any cross type comparison right even in the first solution

Comment: @kaz In the first solution, suppose val is 2 and 2 appears in the vector twice. You said you want to replace each 2 with 2.5 in that case, but you can't because x is `vector<int>`--it would just floor it right back to 2. There are various way to handle that, but you're in a better position than I am to judge which is best.